# How to connect 2 anonymous inbound callers with Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have read a couple similar posts here on SO, however the responses do not explaiin *how*, they only explain that it is possible with Twilio. If a Twilio Evangelist could give me some specific direction on this it would be greatly appreciated.

The idea is *(Caller A)* calls *(Twilio Number)*. Twilio stores Caller A's number until a second caller is achieved.

Once *(Caller B)* calls the same *(Twilio Number)* he is connected to Caller A.

This is at random, and handling many requests at the same time. Once Caller A and Caller B are connected, their numbers are removed from the storage so nobody else will be connected with them.

Rinse repeat.

Comment: Would <conference> work for you? https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference You'll need your own server side logic to restrict two callers, also there no such a thing like 'their numbers are removed from the storage' at Twilio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do this using [`Enqueue`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue) and [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue). First you need to [create your queue using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue#list-post). This can be done ahead of time.

I'm going to use Ruby for the example here, however you can see what this looks like in other languages in our documentation.

```
require "twilio-ruby"
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"], ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"])
queue = client.queues.create(:friendly_name => "call_roulette")
puts queue.sid
```

You'll need to save the Queue Sid and friendly name, you'll use them to connect to the queue later.

Then, when a person calls you need to check whether there is anyone in the queue waiting. If there is then you connect the two callers, if there isn't then you place that caller into the queue and wait for another call.

When the call is made, Twilio will send an HTTP request to the URL you supply in the [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming). You need to respond with the correct 
 based on the conditions above.

This example uses [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) as the web framework.

```
require "twilio-ruby"
require "sinatra"

client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"], ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"])

post "/call" do
  queue = client.queues.get(QUEUE_SID)
  if queue.current_size == 0
    twiml = "<Response><Enqueue>#{QUEUE_FRIENDLY_NAME}</Enqueue></Response>"
  else
    twiml = "<Response><Dial><Queue>#{QUEUE_FRIENDLY_NAME}</Queue></Dial></Response>"
  end
  return twiml
end
```

When the queue is empty, we use Enqueue to put the caller in the queue, when the queue has someone in it, we use Dial and Queue to dial the person in the Queue.

Let me know if that helps at all.